# Is there any way to apply javascript function on current open page url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
   <div><li class="item-list1"></li>
        <ul>
          <li class="item"><a href='/link1'>link1</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href='/link2'>link2</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href='/link3'>link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

   <div><li class="item-list2"></li>
        <ul>
          <li class="item"><a href='/link4'>link4</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href='/link5'>link5</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href='/link6'>link6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Basically I want to apply JavaScript property on the grandparent of the current URL.

Like if the current open link is link4 then I want to find grandparent of the open link that is `item-list2`

I am doing **window.location.href().parent().parent()** but it not helps.

**Edit:**
Thanks, everyone for helping me out,
solution I got is given below:

```
const pathname = window.location.pathname     
var li_attr  = $(`a[href='${pathname}']`).closed("ul").prev("li")
```

*as  suggested by [@bad_kotya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12804871/bad-kotya) and [@freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m)*

Comment: JS does not work by wishful thinking. `window.location.href` is a string, not an object with parent objects. What do you mean by "parent of current url"? If you opened a popup, then window.opener is the parent of the page. If you mean _I want to find the className of the LI that is the container of the link that is currently showing in the location bar_, then that is another question

Comment: @anand It ain't too clear what you're asking. Are you trying to use JavaScript to find the parent list item element  of a list item element?

Comment: FYI `item-list2` isn't a parent of `link4` because you close the `li` before starting the next `ul` - so you'd never get it with `.parent().parent()` or `.closest()` - best would be `.closest("ul").prev("li")`

Comment: As I understand what you're asking:  How to find `link4` based on the URL *and then* how to find `item-list2` from `link4`.

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah you are right, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
const pathname = window.location.pathname
$(`a[href='${pathname}']`).parent().parent()
```

Comment: @mplungjan window.location.pathname.replace(/\/$/,"")

Comment: You ARE quoting. Missed it because of the template literal. So it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid.

Once it is valid you can do this:

```js
const pathname= new URL("https://www.yoursite.com/link4").pathname; // location.pathname; // on your server
console.log(pathname); 
// must be quoted due to the / in the pathname 
const $link = $("[href='" + pathname + "']"); // you can use a template literal too
const $parentUl = $link.closest("ul")
const $ulContainer = $parentUl.closest("li");
console.log($ulContainer.attr("class"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="item-list1">
      <ul>
        <li class="item">
          <a href='/link1'>link1</a></li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href='/link2'>link2</a></li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href='/link3'>link3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="item-list2">
      <ul>
        <li class="item">
          <a href='/link4'>link4</a></li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href='/link5'>link5</a></li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href='/link6'>link6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```